# How to use rowSums() in "dplyr" when including missing data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use the function `rowSums` in `dplyr` and came across some difficulties with missing data. The example data is `mtcars`. The objective is to estimate the sum of three variables of `mpg`, `cyl` and `disp` by row. However, the results seems incorrect with the following R code when there are missing values within a specific row (see variable `new1` and `new2` in the output). Any comments and suggestions are appreciated!

```
data<-mtcars%>%
mutate(
  mpg=case_when(mpg>25~NA_real_,TRUE~as.numeric(mpg)), # generate missing data in "mpg"
  new1=rowSums(.[c("mpg","cyl","disp")],na.rm=FALSE), # method1: row sum, treat NA as NA?
  new2=rowSums(.[c("mpg","cyl","disp")],na.rm=TRUE), # method2: row sum, treat NA as zero?
  new3=mpg+cyl+disp # method3: row sum, by hand
    )

data
```

**The output is listed below:**

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  new1  new2  new3
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 187.0 187.0 187.0
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 187.0 187.0 187.0
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 134.8 134.8 134.8
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 285.4 285.4 285.4
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 386.7 386.7 386.7
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 249.1 249.1 249.1
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 382.3 382.3 382.3
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 175.1 175.1 175.1
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 167.6 167.6 167.6
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 192.8 192.8 192.8
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 191.4 191.4 191.4
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 300.2 300.2 300.2
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 301.1 301.1 301.1
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 299.0 299.0 299.0
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 490.4 490.4 490.4
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 478.4 478.4 478.4
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 462.7 462.7 462.7
18   NA   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 115.1 115.1    NA
19   NA   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 110.1 110.1    NA
20   NA   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 109.0 109.0    NA
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 145.6 145.6 145.6
22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 341.5 341.5 341.5
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 327.2 327.2 327.2
24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 371.3 371.3 371.3
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 427.2 427.2 427.2
26   NA   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 110.3 110.3    NA
27   NA   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2 150.3 150.3    NA
28   NA   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 129.5 129.5    NA
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 374.8 374.8 374.8
30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 170.7 170.7 170.7
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 324.0 324.0 324.0
32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 146.4 146.4 146.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are not what you expect because the insertion of NAs in `mpg` is in the same `mutate` statement as variables `new*`; hence, R still considers the previous values that were in variable `mpg`. By using another `mutate` step before, we manage to obtain the desided results

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    mpg = case_when(mpg > 25 ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ as.numeric(mpg)) # generate missing data in "mpg"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    new1 = rowSums(.[c("mpg","cyl","disp")], na.rm = FALSE), # method1: row sum, treat NA as NA?
    new2 = rowSums(.[c("mpg","cyl","disp")], na.rm = TRUE), # method2: row sum, treat NA as zero?
    new3 = mpg + cyl + disp # method3: row sum, by hand
  )
```

Output

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  new1  new2  new3
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 187.0 187.0 187.0
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 187.0 187.0 187.0
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 134.8 134.8 134.8
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 285.4 285.4 285.4
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 386.7 386.7 386.7
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 249.1 249.1 249.1
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 382.3 382.3 382.3
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 175.1 175.1 175.1
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 167.6 167.6 167.6
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 192.8 192.8 192.8
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 191.4 191.4 191.4
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 300.2 300.2 300.2
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 301.1 301.1 301.1
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 299.0 299.0 299.0
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 490.4 490.4 490.4
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 478.4 478.4 478.4
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 462.7 462.7 462.7
18   NA   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1    NA  82.7    NA
19   NA   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2    NA  79.7    NA
20   NA   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1    NA  75.1    NA
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 145.6 145.6 145.6
22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 341.5 341.5 341.5
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 327.2 327.2 327.2
24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 371.3 371.3 371.3
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 427.2 427.2 427.2
26   NA   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1    NA  83.0    NA
27   NA   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2    NA 124.3    NA
28   NA   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2    NA  99.1    NA
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 374.8 374.8 374.8
30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 170.7 170.7 170.7
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 324.0 324.0 324.0
32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 146.4 146.4 146.4
```

Answer (score 2):

did you try `cbind` in place of `c`:

```
data<-mtcars%>%
  mutate(
    mpg=case_when(mpg>25~NA_real_,TRUE~as.numeric(mpg)), # generate missing data in "mpg"
    new1=rowSums(cbind(mpg,cyl,disp),na.rm=FALSE), # method1: row sum, treat NA as NA?
    new2=rowSums(cbind(mpg,cyl,disp),na.rm=TRUE), # method2: row sum, treat NA as zero?
    new3=mpg+cyl+disp # method3: row sum, by hand
  )
```

`data` seems what you'd expect:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  new1  new2  new3
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 187.0 187.0 187.0
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 187.0 187.0 187.0
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 134.8 134.8 134.8
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 285.4 285.4 285.4
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 386.7 386.7 386.7
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 249.1 249.1 249.1
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 382.3 382.3 382.3
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 175.1 175.1 175.1
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 167.6 167.6 167.6
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 192.8 192.8 192.8
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 191.4 191.4 191.4
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 300.2 300.2 300.2
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 301.1 301.1 301.1
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 299.0 299.0 299.0
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 490.4 490.4 490.4
16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 478.4 478.4 478.4
17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 462.7 462.7 462.7
18   NA   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1    NA  82.7    NA
19   NA   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2    NA  79.7    NA
20   NA   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1    NA  75.1    NA
21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 145.6 145.6 145.6
22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 341.5 341.5 341.5
23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 327.2 327.2 327.2
24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 371.3 371.3 371.3
25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 427.2 427.2 427.2
26   NA   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1    NA  83.0    NA
27   NA   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2    NA 124.3    NA
28   NA   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2    NA  99.1    NA
29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 374.8 374.8 374.8
30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 170.7 170.7 170.7
31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 324.0 324.0 324.0
32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 146.4 146.4 146.4
```

Comment: This is really a cool answer! It works following to your suggestions. Thanks!